# How to deal with subquery returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I only want to run the parent select if the subselect is not null. Unsure how to achieve this using sql query :-

```
SELECT * from schools 
    WHERE `district_id` =
    (SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194')
```

Comment: That is what your query does.  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: if SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194' returns null I get every row from schools

Comment: If SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194' returns an id, I get the rows with that district id

Comment: Check `SELECT COALESCE` - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

Comment: If the subquery is null the `=` operation can't be true (even if `district_id` is also null) and no rows are returned by the parent query. So it actually already does what you want, does it not?

Comment: it returns all rows that do not have a district_id value and thats what im looking to avoid

Comment: so, SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194' returns null, then SELECT * from schools WHERE `district_id` = null returns rows with no district ids. I don't want that. I'd like the outer query to run if the sub query returns a value and not null

Comment: I highly doubt that, as `NULL = NULL` is not true, so no rows fulfill that condition and the outer query returns no rows, not all. At least, that's how it should be. Can you set up a Fiddle that shows that opposite behavior you claim happening?

Comment: Wait a minute... You don't have the string `'NULL'` in that column, do you? Or an empty string? Because these are not `NULL` values and would explain the behavior you describe... If that's the case sanitize the data and use (the real) `NULL` instead of that strings.

Comment: @stickybit Sonofabitch! an empty string. thanks

Comment: @SamLuther If you have empty string, the specified behavior is still not expected i think.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir you're right, I removed the empty string, still have the same issues

Comment: @SamLuther Go to my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9440a2/2) and produce the issue.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir thanks but stickybit had it correct. using (the real) NULL did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Seems you just need to use `IN` like below :

```
SELECT * from schools 
WHERE `district_id` in
(SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194')
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9440a2/2)

Comment: I tried that, no go, still returns rows with district_id that are null

Comment: Seems something is wrong in your database! Check the fiddle and produce the issue you are having. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9440a2/2

Answer (score 1):

you should run your sql query like ...

```
SELECT * from schools 
WHERE `district_id` = 
(SELECT district_id from schools 
    WHERE `school_id` = '0023194'
    AND 
    district_id IS NOT NULL) 
AND district_id IS NOT NULL
```

> district_id IS NOT NULL
>   to prevent district_id not null

Comment: Not what i'm looking for, that query returns the same number of rows as SELECT * from schools WHERE `district_id` = (SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194')

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IN` operator because IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions. In your condition, `=` compares only one condition but if you have multiple record of this school_id, = can't evaluate it.

```
SELECT * from schools WHERE `district_id` in (SELECT district_id from schools WHERE `school_id` = '0023194')
```